# How to do Unicode aware fold-case to lower case in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, unicode

I need to implement the Scheme `char-foldcase` function for my [Scheme implementation in JavaScript](https://lips.js.org/). The [R7RS spec](https://small.r7rs.org/attachment/r7rs.pdf) says that `char-foldcase` should use:

> Unicode simple case-folding algorithm

I was checking the [GNU Kawa](https://www.gnu.org/software/kawa/index.html) (Scheme implementation).

```lisp
#|kawa:7|# (number->string (char->integer (char-foldcase (integer->char #x03D0))) 16)
;; ==> 3b2
```

And it works correctly. The hex numbers are uppercase and lowercase Greek Unicode letters: `ϐ` and `β`. The examples are taken from [Unicode case folding to upper case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20181505/387194) question.

But in JavaScript:

```js
String.fromCharCode(0x03D0).toLowerCase().charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
// ==> 3d0
```

This means that JavaScript toLowerCase is not Unicode Aware. Is there any alternative to getting lowercase for all Unicode characters in JavaScript?

I was checking [toLocaleLowerCase](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase) but it requires to use proper locale. And I want to have something universal that will convert all Unicode characters.

Comment: I'm not aware of any existing solution, but given that there are fewer than 2000 entries in https://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/CaseFolding.txt, a pure JS implementation sounds trivial.

Comment: Folding depend on locale.

Comment: @gog thanks for the link, I think that I can write some code that will generate the folding for me. I already have a similar code to detect numerical Unicode characters. I only saved Zero for each numeric symbol sequence.

Comment: @jcubic: if you work with other unicode props a lot, perhaps it would make more sense to use the full UCD (https://www.unicode.org/ucd/) rather than derived data. There are already npm modules that handle the UCD.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi: you're thinking of _mapping_ here, not _folding_ . Folding is intended to be language-neutral (https://www.unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html#5)

Comment: What is exactly the problem? Lowercasing is a operation to change a the case of a string. Casefolding is an operation to remove case distinctions (and in somecases will fold to uppercase). U+03D0 is a lowercase character and will lowercase to itself. It uppercases to U+0392, and has a compatibility mapping to U+03B2 and casefolds to U+03B2. The standard uppercase/lowercase pair for Greek is U+03B2 and U+0392. U+03DO is a variant form of the lowercase Beta.

Comment: @Andj the problem is to implement this in JavaScript. But I already implemented that by writing the code that generates the mapping based on @​gog document.

Comment: @jcubic in your question you were comparing casefolding in Kawa with lowercasing in Javascript for U+03D0. You compared two fundamentally different operations. In both cases you got the correct result. You want to implement case folding, but discussion and comparison with lowercasing is taking you off course.

Comment: Probably best to look at how its implemented in the foldcase Node module. Although if you are intending to implement case folding, you should also think about NFKC_CF, which would be needed for canonical caseless matching,

Comment: @Andj I know they are different operations, but you're probably aware that JavaScript doesn't have case folding only lowercase. This is just an example of the only code you can write in JavaScript.

Comment: @jcubic, I've always preferred to do internationalisation server side rather than client side. javascript i18n is fairly limited to say the least and too focused purely on l10n. In terms of casefolding only, https://github.com/dougmoscrop/fold-case could be a building block.

Comment: Also https://github.com/rapid-scheme/foldcase and https://github.com/ar-nelson/foldcase